# need script file to change line in files of my folder

Tags: awk, sed

So many files in my folder has below format:

```
L1_ERROR(A, B, "A");
```

Would like to change

```
L1_EXCPT(B,A);
```

please help me.

Comment: @Kalanidhi M.  I see in you edit that you have moved all to one line.  Is this correct?

Comment: As always with these sort of problems, changing the target line is trivial but NOT changing other lines that you don't want to change is the difficult part. Post some additional lines of input showing lines that you think a script could confuse with your target line and so will be difficult to avoid changing (e.g. a line that starts with `BILL1_ERROR(A, B,"A");`).

Answer (score 0):

This may do:

```
cat file
test
L1_ERROR(A, B,
          "A");
data
```

```
awk '/L1_ERROR/ {print "L1_EXCPT(B,A);";getline;next}1' file
test
L1_EXCPT(B,A);
data
```

Or this can be used to avoid using `getline`

```
awk '/L1_ERROR/ {print "L1_EXCPT(B,A);";a=NR+1;next} NR!=a' file
```

Comment: Sorry, I think missed something

Comment: @user2314818 Is your main post correct now?  I see some has ajusted it agiain.  Do also post some more example.